# Display hours,minutes,seconds,msecs on xaxis in bokeh plot

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I want to display xaxis in below format. It should include hr,min,secs,msecs format

14:38:21:701, 14:38:21:702..

Below is the code I have written

```
    #!/usr/bin/python3
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import DatetimeTickFormatter, ColumnDataSource, PrintfTickFormatter
from pandas import ExcelWriter, ExcelFile

weight = pd.read_excel('file_name.xlsx')

source = ColumnDataSource(weight)

#Take data  and present in a graph
output_file("test.html")

p = figure(plot_width=1500, plot_height=400)
p.left[0].formatter.use_scientific = False
p.xaxis[0].formatter.use_scientific = False
  
#Need to modify this format to display hours,minutes,seconds,msecs
p.xaxis[0].formatter = PrintfTickFormatter(format="%sms")


p.scatter(x='Time',y='Bearer ID 5 WM Low', color = "navy",source=source,legend_label='Bearer ID 5 WM Low')
p.scatter(x='Time',y='Bearer ID 5 VM Count', color = "red",source=source,legend_label='Bearer ID 5 VM Count')
show(p)
```

[Below is the output for it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ShIO.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could use DatetimeFormatter instead of PrintfTickFormatter.

Visit [DatetimeTickFormatter](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html#bokeh.models.formatters.DatetimeTickFormatter) for the documentation